# How to coordinate interactions between multiple data visualizations, particularly when one of them uses nesting? JavaScript and D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested, data-visualization, interactive

For a project I am attempting to have three visualizations for data based on car stats, where if you hover over one, the others will show the affects of that hovering as well.
The first is a bar graph, the second is a scatterplot, and the third is a line graph. For the line graph I wanted to group by manufacturer so that I don't have a couple hundred lines on my line graph, as the plot coordinates on the x and y are acceleration and model year. The other two don't need to be grouped in this way because one of their axes is the manufacturer.

I have the interactions from the line graph to the other two working since there is no nesting on the bar or scatterplot, and both the scatterplot and the bar graph can affect each other perfectly fine, but since the data is nested for the line graph, I can't seem to figure out how to access it, as the way I was doing it for the other two (using filtering) does not seem to work.

Below I am first showing where I am trying to create interactions when the mouse hovers (this is for the bar graph), and below that I include how my line graph is set up to show how it works. All I want is to make the corresponding line stand out more from the others by thickening the stroke when I hover over the bar or plot (in the scatterplot), and then go back to the normal size upon moving my cursor.
I followed the tutorial on the D3 website for line graphs, so there shouldn't be anything particularly wrong with that code.

Creating the bars for the bar graph, the mouseover and mouseout are the important parts:

```
var path1 = svg1.selectAll("myRect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", x1(0.1) )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.Manufacturer); })
    .attr("height", y1.bandwidth() )
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x1(d.Cylinders); })
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
      return color1(d.Cylinders);
    })
    .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
      svg1.selectAll('rect')
            .filter(function(f) {
                return f.Manufacturer === d.Manufacturer;
            })
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
              return color4(d.Cylinders);
            })
      svg2.selectAll('circle')
          .filter(function(f) {
            return f.Manufacturer === d.Manufacturer;
          })
          .attr('r', 9)
          .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color5(d.Horsepower);
          });
      svg3.selectAll('path') //THIS IS THE LINE GRAPH
        .filter(function(f) {
           console.log(this)
          return ;           // <-------This is where I don't know what to return to just get one line
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", 7)
})
 .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
      svg1.selectAll('rect')
          .filter(function(f) {
            return f.Manufacturer === d.Manufacturer;
          })
          .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color1(d.Cylinders);
          });
      svg2.selectAll('circle')
           .filter(function(f) {
            return f.Manufacturer === d.Manufacturer;
           })
           .attr('r', 5)
           .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color2(d.Acceleration);
          });
      d3.selectAll('path')           //DELESLECTING LINE GRAPH
           .filter(function(f) {
            return f.key === d.Manufacturer; //this is what I tried before but it doesn't work
           })
           .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
 });
```

Creating the line graph:

```
var sumstat = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.Manufacturer;})
.entries(data);

// Add X axis 
var x3 = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([69, 84])
.range([ 0, width3 ]);

svg3.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height3 + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x3).ticks(5));

// Add Y axis
var y3 = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([8, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.Acceleration; })])
.range([ height3, 0 ]);
svg3.append("g")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y3));

var div3 = d3.select("#my_div").append("div")
     .attr("class", "#tool_tip")
     .style("opacity", 0)
     .style("font-size", "xx-large");

// color palette
var res = sumstat.map(function(d){ return d.key }) // list of group names
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(res)
.range(['darkolivegreen','darkred','palevioletred','indianred', 'hotpink']) 

// Draw the line
svg3.selectAll(".line")
  .data(sumstat)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", function(d){
      return d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x3(d.ModelYear); })
        .y(function(d) { return y3(+d.Acceleration); })
        (d.values)
    })
    .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
      //highlight;
      svg3.selectAll("path")
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.9)
      d3.select(this)
          .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key)})
          .attr("stroke-width", 6)
      svg1.selectAll('rect')
            .filter(function(f) { 
              return f.Manufacturer === d.key;
            })
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
              return color4(d.Cylinders);
            })
      svg2.selectAll('circle')
            .filter(function(f) {
                return f.Manufacturer === d.key;
            })
            .attr('r', 9)
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
              return color5(d.Horsepower);
            });
  })
 .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
      svg3.selectAll("path")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      d3.select(this)
          .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key)})
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      svg1.selectAll('rect')
          .filter(function(f) {
            return f.Manufacturer === d.key;
           })
          .attr("fill", function (d) {
             return color1(d.Cylinders);
           })
      svg2.selectAll('circle')
          .filter(function(f) {
            return f.Manufacturer === d.key;
           })
           .attr('r', 5)
           .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color2(d.Horsepower);
          });
  });
```

Any assistance I can get would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet or fiddle?

Comment: I have never used fiddle before, so I am not sure I did it right but here is my code @MichaelRovinsky 
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/Cait_L/ocedpuj3/6/)

Comment: I don't know how to add a .csv file to fiddle though.

Comment: Just convert the contents of CSV to JSON and put it as a data object in the JS section: `const data = [... your data here ...]`

Comment: Okay, so I did not think that making it a data object would work without a lot of modification to the data and my code, so I just uploaded the .csv file to my github and linked to it. I hope that is okay as well. I am very new to Javascript, so this is quite a challenge for me.

Comment: This is the link to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Cait_L/ocedpuj3/6/  I see there a URL of a CSV file which is clearly not from GitHub: `./data/a1-cars.csv` ...

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/Cait_L/ocedpuj3/15/](https://jsfiddle.net/Cait_L/ocedpuj3/15/)
It seems that the URL changes when you make new saves. I am sorry, I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured out the problem. It would seem that trying to filter the paths causes an issue because the x and y axes are also technically lines, and thus have paths that are null. I tried

```
svg3.selectAll('path')
          .filter(function(f) {
             console.log(f)
             if(f!=null)
                return f.key === d.Manufacturer;
          })
            .attr("stroke-width",7)
```

In the .on('mouseover') function, and it seems to be working. The issue was the nulls, not the actual accessing of the keys.

Still taking suggestions if there is a better way to do this!